# Fraps with dual monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, screen-capture, screen-recorder

I'm running dual monitors on Windows 7. Is there a way to configure Fraps to record from a specific monitor?

Comment: Another option is Captura. https://mathewsachin.github.io/Captura/. Need ffmpeg for codec.

Answer (score 0):

Fraps isn't really meant to be a general purpose screen capture utility. It's meant for screen captures in games. Take a look at the [Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/snipping-tool) that is built into Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think he asked for taking screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://obsproject.com/index

It's a tool used by most streamers so it's perfectly adapted to dual monitors. You can just choose to store the output as a local file instead of streaming it (or do both at the same time)

Comment: Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on how to recommend software in an answer.  Site standards have changed a bit since this question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a two monitor flight sim setup. I use the monitor directly in front as my main monitor, with it set to forward-looking virtual cockpit most of the time. Second monitor (on left, angled 45 deg.) is the one I use for all other views. Here's my problem: I wanted to use Fraps to record views on my second (side) monitor but discovered Fraps would only record from the monitor that I had declared in Display settings to be the main monitor, i.e., straight ahead. Bummer. Not what I wanted 'cause I don't like flying with my head turned sideways. Then I accidentally discovered that if I didn't display the FSX main screen on the forward-looking monitor at full screen but left a 1/8" margin, Fraps would record from the side monitor--exactly what I wanted! If you disable the red letter messaging while you're recording movies, you can get clean movies with no FSX message clutter.

Comment: This *might* be the start of an answer to the question.  But (1) it’s unclear.  I’ve never heard of FSX; I had to Google it to find out that it is “Flight Simulator X”. (2) It’s not clear that the question is about Flight Simulator, or any other game, so it’s not clear that this is relevant. (3) I can’t tell what your bottom line is.  It seems like you’re saying that Fraps is *never* configurable / controllable; that it always records the main screen, unless you’re running FSX with a 1/8" margin; then it (unconditionally) records from the side monitor.  Can you clarify that please?